# Compiles smoothly, does not run, no output (C)

Tags: c, dev-c++

I was just copying some sample programs taken from the book *The C Programming Language by Kernighan and Ritchie*. This is one of its examples, a program that claims to convert a C-string inputted to its floating point equivalent:

```
#include <ctype.h>

/* atof: convert string s to a double */
double atof(char s[])
{
    double val, power;
    int i, sign;

    for (i = 0; isspace(s[i]); i++); /* skip white spaces */
        sign = (s[i] == '-') ? -1 :1; 

    if (s[i] == '+' || s[i] == '-')
        i++;

    for (val = 0.0; isdigit(s[i]); i++)
        val = 10.0 * val + (s[i] - '0');

    if (s[i] == '.')
        i++;

    for (power = 1.0; isdigit(s[i]); i++) {
        val = 10.0 * val + (s[i] - '0');
        power *= 10.0;
    }       
    return sign * val / power;
}
```

It does compile but I believe it does not run because nothing happens. When I try to "Run" the program, I got this pop-up message:

[image: Source file not compiled]

Where did I go wrong?

Besides I never see the outputs from other sample programs shown in the book.

Comment: Your problem is not with C, but the tool called [tag:dev-c++] - that's what you need to tag into your question!

Comment: Where is your `main` function? Show us that where you actually should use your `atof` function and output it.

Comment: Also: that "program" is missing the **main** function. It is not a program, but a compilation unit. It has a function `atof` that you're supposed to invoke somewhere.

Comment: oh no.....I was having trouble of it for months......I didn't realize it.....I thought it's my fault.....maybe I pushed the dev-c++ way too hardXD.........

Comment: @AndreKampling I can't.....I was just copying a sample program I've seen from the book  "The C Programming Language" by Kernighan and Ritchie.  I don't know how to do that.....I'm sorry...

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I did put a main() function on the program above. It does compile and run, but the output only shows the elapsed time the program is compiled and the classic "Press any key to continue".......I rechecked the code to be sure, but I did not see any mistakes in copying.......Maybe the 1980's book is barely applicable nowadays?

Comment: @BAHUG_OTEN: I have a copy of the second edition: They talking about the main function on page 6.

Answer (score 3):

The main function is the entry point for every C progam that should run self-sufficient. You can read something about it [here on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entry_point#C_and_C.2B.2B):

> The `main()` function is special; normally every C and C++ program must define it exactly once.

If you're programming a library (`.dll` in Windows/`.so` in Linux) you wouldn't provide a `main` function as you just provide functions to other programmers. The library is not a running program itself.

In my copy of the book which is the second edition they talking about the `main` function on page 6.

Provide the following and you will see output you also have to include `#include <stdio.h>`:

```
int main()
{
   /* declare variables and initialize some of them */
   char   doubleStr[] = "3.14";
   double doubleVal;

   /* invoke your atof function */
   doubleVal = atof(doubleStr);

   /* print output to console */
   printf("The string \"%s\" is converted to: %f", doubleStr, doubleVal);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi @BAHUG_OTEN if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have main() function in your code.
That's why you are getting the notification. In C language your program must have a main function to compile and run. The compilation of any program starts from main.
Also the example in book generally have only the code of the required function not the main function, They assume that you know basics of c language.

Add following lines to your code, it will work.

```
int main(void) {
    double a = atof("20");
    printf("%f", a);

    return 0;
}
```