# Unknown errors on multiple lines in C

Tags: c

```
void functionality()
{
   int ll = 5
   char x = 'A';

   for (int i = 0; i < ll; i++)
   {
      printf("c  ", x);
   }
}
```

I am learning C language and I wrote the above snippet. However, it is not running with loads of errors. I cannot seem to find the problem of what is happening here since I followed the code from a tutorial and I have double checked everything.

```
int main()
{
   printf(functionality);
}
```

Comment: It has to be `%c` not just `c` in printf. Did you include needed headers: `#include <stdio.h>`? To have a running program you need a `main` function see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45159215/8051589.

Comment: You had some *errors*. Could you share them with us?

Comment: You should read a C book first.

Comment: Please present a [mcve].

Comment: http://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/RqYGh3

Comment: _It is not running with a lot of errors._ So it does run without errors? Or doesn't it run but the compiler spits out a lot of errors? Please have a look at the [ask] section and then create a [mcve].

Comment: token that is not allowed by the formal grammar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

on the first glance of your code I can see 3 problems:

the line `int ll = 5` is missing a `;`

**AND**

the line `printf("c  ", x);` should be `printf("%c  ", x);`

**AND**

a missing `}` at the end

For next time, try to also provide the error codes, please.

The main function should look like this:

```
int main(){
   functionality();
}
```

The function is void, hence no need to call it in a `print` statement. Also, we call a function by first stating the name of the function followed by the curly braces. I suggest that you first familiarize yourself with the basic syntax of the language first.

Comment: Hi this seems to have removed many errors but there is still another one in main function

Comment: can you edit your post to include your main function, please?

Comment: done please check my question for edit

Comment: updated my answer for you...

Comment: I will try it nnow

Comment: Yes there is output! Thanks

Comment: The `main` function should return something as the `main` function in C returns an `int`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3727051/why-does-a-main-function-without-a-return-statement-return-value-12. For example `EXIT_SUCCESS` or `0`.

Answer (score 3):

These errors are not *unknown*:

1. There is no `main` function, so there's nothing to run.
2. You are missing a closing `}` at the end of this function.
3. You are missing a `;` at the end of `int ll = 5;`
4. Your `printf` call is malformed, Did you want  `printf("%c  ", x);`?
5. Where is your `#include <stdio.h>` (or does your compiler bring that in automatically?).

Comment: hey thanks but i included only function with errors I have a main function

Comment: The functionality(**void**) is missing.

Comment: OP changed it now there is a wrong main function...

Comment: @AndreKampling: The C standard requires compilers to add `return 0;` to `main` if missing.

Comment: My comment (`OP changed it now [...]`) was about: `printf(functionality);` in the main function of the OP. But thank you, you answered my other comment under David Farrugias answer, as I didn't know that fact.

Comment: Just for completeness: The `return 0` is just added in the C99 standard. For ANSI C or C89 that doesn't apply, see the SO answer I refer to.

Answer (score 0):

you are missing a **;** at the end of the line int ll=5

change the `c` to `%c` in the `printf()` function as follows

```
printf("%c",x);
```

also make sure you close all the braces properly at the end of the function.

make sure you have a main function in your program,and also include header files